# Consider the IVP: $x^2y''+5xy'−5y=0,y(1)=0,y'(1)=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the IVP:

$$x^2y''+5xy'−5y=0,y(1)=0,y'(1)=1$$

Treating this as a Cauchy-Euler equation, find the unique solution on $(0,\infty)$.

my work

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Dividing by $x^2$, we have
$$y'' + 5 \dfrac{y'}x - 5 \dfrac{y}{x^2} = 0$$
This can be rewritten as
$$y'' + 5 \dfrac{d}{dx}\left(\dfrac{y}x\right) = 0 \implies y' + 5\dfrac{y}x = c_1$$
Setting $y(x)=xv(x)$, we obtain that
$$y'(x) = xv'(x) + v(x)$$
Hence, we have
$$xv' + v + 5v=c_1 \implies xv' + 6v = c_1 \implies xv' + 6v-c_1 = 0 \implies \dfrac{dv}{6v-c_1} + \dfrac{dx}x = 0$$
This gives us that
$$\dfrac16 \ln(v-c_2) + \ln(x) = c_3 \implies (v-c_2)x^6 = 6c_3 \implies v(x) = \dfrac{k_1}{x^6} + k_2 \implies y(x) = \dfrac{k_1}{x^5} + k_2x$$

Now $y(1) = 0 \implies k_2 = -k_1$. And $y'(1) = 1 \implies k_2 - 5k_1 = 1$.

This gives us $k_1 = -1/6$ and $k_2 = 1/6$. Hence, the solution is
$$y(x) = \dfrac16\left(x-\dfrac1{x^5}\right)$$

Comment: Not a bad answer, but not quite what the question asks

Answer (score 0):

Note that the problem asks to treat this as a Cauchy-Euler equation (you're doing a power series approach). Doing so, we find a solution of the form $y = x^m$. Taking derivatives and plugging in gives
$$ x^2m(m-1)x^{m-2} + 5xmx^{m-1} - 5x^m = 0$$
or
$$ m(m-1) + 5m - 5 = 0 $$
$$ m^2 + 4m - 5 $$

This gives $m = 1$ and $m = -5$, so the general solution is
$$ y(x) = c_1 x + c_2x^{-5} $$

Now apply the initial conditions to find the constants.